# Get the column width by index instead of position

Tags: java, nattable

I would like to get the column width by index instead of position.

To get the width of columns currently viewed I can use this.

```
bodyLayer.getColumnWidthByPosition(columnPosition)
```

Is it possible to get the column width by index instead? This would allow me to get the column widths of columns that aren't within the viewport. I would like to loop through every column and get its width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if you operate on a deeper layer like the DataLayer. The ViewportLayer will not return you any width of a column that is currently not visible. That would violate the design of the ViewportLayer.